# How to DRY multiple consecutive for loops

Tags: c++, dry

```
for (int j = 0; j < BOARD_SIZE; ++j)
{
    setcolor(m_board[i][j]);

    std::cout << color << "      " << "\033[m";
}

std::cout << std::endl;

for (int j = 0; j < BOARD_SIZE; ++j)
{
    setcolor(m_board[i][j]);

    std::cout << color << "  " << m_board[i][j] << "  " << "\033[m";
}

std::cout << std::endl;

for (int j = 0; j < BOARD_SIZE; ++j)
{       
    setcolor(m_board[i][j]);

    std::cout << color << "      " << "\033[m"; 
}

std::cout << std::endl;
```

So that is my code (they are all nested in another for loop, hence the `i`). The first and last loop are the same and the middle one only differs by outputting a variable instead of only blank spaces. I tried putting the top and bottom loop into a lambda, which looks like this:

```
auto draw_blank = [&]()
{
    for (int j = 0; j < BOARD_SIZE; ++j)
    {
        setcolor(m_board[i][j]);

        std::cout << color << "       " << "\033[m";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
};

draw_blank();

for (int i = 0; i < BOARD_SIZE; ++i)
{
    setcolor(m_board[i][j]);

    std::cout << color << "  0" << m_board[i][j] << "  " << "\033[m"    
}

std::cout << std::endl;

draw_blank();
```

But it looks a bit more complicated and I till write the loop twice. So is it pobbile to write a structure that is the same for all 3 loops and only changes the one output line in the middle loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a parameter to your lambda like this:

```
auto draw_board = [&](bool clear)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < BOARD_SIZE; ++j)
    {
        setcolor(m_board[i][j]);

        std::cout << color << "  ";
        if (clear)
        {
            std::cout << "  ";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << m_board[i][j];
        }

        std::cout << "  \033[m";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
};

draw_board(true);
draw_board(false);    
draw_board(true);
```

Comment: Oh, my god... How did I miss that. Thank you!